# org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "$1"

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

I am getting this PSQLException:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "$1"
  Position: 37
```

When I run the following code:

```
ps = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT current_timestamp + INTERVAL ?;");
ps.setString(1, "30 minutes");
System.out.println(ps);
rs = ps.executeQuery();
```

However, the println function displays this in the console:

```
SELECT current_timestamp + INTERVAL '30 minutes'
```

Anyone know what is wrong? The query in the console runs fine in pgAdmin so I know it isn't a syntax error.

Comment: Makes no difference, the semicolon is perfectly valid

Comment: the query works for me, is this is the actual code or do you have any variable in place of "30 minutes"

Comment: This is the actual code... Are you running postgres?

Comment: There is a bug with setting strings as an interval, I am sure of it... `setString` works for other strings and `setInt` works too...

Comment: It seems to be [postgresql bug](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/9475581B-E5F2-404C-84CC-7D3774B590BF@fastcrypt.com)

Comment: what driver version are you using I am using 9.1 and it dint gave me any sql error

Comment: I downloaded the JDBC42 Postgresql Driver from `https://jdbc.postgresql.org/download.html`

Comment: Have you tried the syntax `CAST(? AS interval)` as suggested in the [response](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/25249.1131295774@sss.pgh.pa.us) to the bug linked by @herry?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Although the syntax `INTERVAL '30 minutes'` is valid when you write SQL directly in a console, it is actually considered to be an **interval literal** and won't work where the string that follows the word `INTERVAL` is not a literal string.

Prepared statements in PostgreSQL are implemented on the server side using [`PREPARE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-prepare.html) and each `?` is seen as an actual variable on the server. This is also why it complains about `$1` although you never wrote a `$` in your statement.

Therefore, literal syntax does not work for a prepared statement.

Don't let the string representation (result of `println`) of the prepared statement confuse you - it's not what the server sees. The server sees a variable there.

Thus, you need to use syntax that takes a string (which can be a variable or a literal) and converts it to interval. For example `?::INTERVAL` or `CAST(? AS INTERVAL)`.

This is therefore *not* a bug.

Comment: Thanks very much!

`ps = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT current_timestamp + ?::INTERVAL;");`

This works as expected, shame that this is not documented in the JSP book I bought :)

Comment: Well, it's a JSP book, not a PostgreSQL one, I suppose. Each DBMS has its own quirks and some are related to the specific way it decides to implement the JDBC contract.

Comment: Very good point indeed... when something is not working how I expect, always quick to point the finger haha

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a Postgres bug and so I thought of a dirty hack to get around this...

```
ps = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT current_timestamp + INTERVAL ?;");
ps.setString(1, "30 minutes");
ps = connection.prepareStatement(ps.toString());
rs = ps.executeQuery();
```

I wonder if this will ever get fixed?

Comment: Why was this answer down-voted ? are there any downsides for this approach ?

Comment: It should be downvoted, it was a quick/dirty fix until the correct answer of casting came along. Shouldn't create a prepared statement, and then create another one with the toString of the first prepared statement. It works, but, it's not the right way of doing it.