# How to replace param in commas?

Tags: java, postgresql, groovy, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

I try to replace param wrapped by commans with namedParameterJdbcTemplate, but it doesn't work:

This code (groovy)

```
def params = [hours: 24]
def query = "SELECT count(*) FROM Movie WHERE (now() - last_updated) < interval ':hours hours'"
def rowCount = namedParameterJdbcTemplate.queryForInt(query, params);
```

returns

> nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: invalid
>   input syntax for type interval: ":hours hours"

How to replace param in commas with namedParameterJdbcTemplate?

Comment: See [my answer on a related question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33059195/4125191)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33059195/716027) helped me. Here is fixed version - it works but I'm not sure that this is the best way to solve the problem:

```
def params = [hoursInterval: hours + " hours"]
def query = "SELECT count(*) FROM Movie WHERE (now() - last_updated) < :hoursInterval::INTERVAL"
def rowCount = namedParameterJdbcTemplate.queryForInt(query, params);
```